# python - start multiple binaries from python and monitor their status

Tags: python, c++, subprocess, binaryfiles

I have several executable C++ binaries that I need to start from a python script. Depending on the status of these executables, the script is going to do some stuff. Let's say, I start 4 separate programs and they are all running. My script needs to make sure these 4 programs are running happily and have not crashed. If it did, the script will send an email with the info in the lines of "Process XYZ failed at this time"

I am on a Linux machine. I tried various combinations of subprocess tricks but no dice. I imagine I may need to utilize threading and keep a "watchdog" on the processes it started. Ideally, the script needs to start these programs in separate terminal windows, so a total of 4 terminal windows.
Below is my attempt:

```
import subprocess as sp
clear = sp.call('clear')

try:
    comm = sp.Popen(['xterm', '-e', '~/stuff/comm'])
    while sp.Pipe == -1:
         ...do stuff
except sp.PIPE == -2:
    ...send email.
```

The problem with the above approach has been, if I kill the program the script started, the script does not realize that it was killed.

Aah, brain is fried, I will try to add more coherent info later but if anyone already knows what I am trying to accomplish, I will greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on a Linux machine, you can use signals, specifically SIGCHLD. This signal is sent to a parent process when any of its child processes dies. The default action is to ignore it, so you need to install a handler to handle it:

```
import os
import signal

def sigchld(sig, frame):
    (pid, r) = os.wait()
    print pid, "exited with", ("signal %d" % (r & 0x7f) if os.WIFSIGNALED(r) else "exit code %d" % (r >> 8))

signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, sigchld)
# run your subprocesses here
```